# No component render on any Routing except for app.component its self

Tags: angular

Im trying to route to my login by default

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../app/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But it doesnt display any of my components

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MemberService } from 'src/app/member.service';
import { Member } from 'src/app/member.model';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'src/app/entry.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
```

Am i missing something About how this works?

**Note my Login Component isnt showing up so I cant even see the Register Link**

Login Html Currently

```
 <a routerLink="register" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
```

app-component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 

<p>app.component is running!</p>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: try [routerLink]="['/register']"

Comment: ```routerLink="/register"```

Comment: Shouldve mentioned that my login isnt even showing up so cant even see the routerlink

Comment: have you declared login component in app.module.ts?

Comment: try changing redirectTo: '/login' => redirectTo: 'login'

remove slash from redirectTo

Comment: I did add it to the app.module yes

Comment: I tried still no render @zainhassan

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: None, Which is why im here. Id usually just straggle until i get it but Theres no errors nothing in logs going wrong so im very confused

Comment: can you reproduce on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdec3f?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts

More or less all the code I used there, Dono how that site works tho

Comment: did you import  `AppRoutingModule ` in the `AppModule`?

Comment: @Andrei I did yes, I added some of the more noteworthy imports to my little app module snipping

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6znqhn?file=src/app/login/login.component.html

Comment: Hmm what did u change? @zainhassan I cant seem to spot a difference besides like really minor things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you initialise a model in the constructer it creates a error but doesnt log it, So the component doesnt display so All i did was change the login component constructor to not have the entry model initiated inside of it but rather above it

```
entry: Entry;
constructor(private memberservice: MemberService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private persist: PersistService
    ){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '/' from the redirectTo present in redirectTo: '/login'
for it to work.

Example can be:

export const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', redirectTo: 'component-one', pathMatch: 'full' },{ path: 'component-one', component: ComponentOne },{ path: 'component-two', component: ComponentTwo }];

Please try it this way

Comment: Actually resolved it turns out I Initiated a model in the constructor in the component and that apparently breaks the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to route directly to login component when loading the web application, use following code,

```
 {path: '', component: LoginAndSignupComponent},
 {path: 'adminDashboard', component: AdminDashBoardComponent, children: [
       {path: 'createCustomer', component: CreateCustomerComponent},
 ]},
```

]